# Logging a state in a function after updating it, still outputs the initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've encountered something unusual when trying to adjust state from a function in React.

A simple example includes trying to change the state, `testState` that holds a string. I would think that I can use `setTestState()` from within a function to change the string and see it's changed value. However, I've noticed that `console.log(testState)` outputs the same state, and so it appears `setTestState(...)` is not doing anything. But, the rendered state uses the updated string.

So why is it that `console.log(tempState)` displays the original state and not the new on? I've been unable to find answers this. The code I've used is below. Any suggestions would be great.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {  
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState("previous state");

  useEffect(() => {
    setGrid();
  }, []);

  const setGrid = () => {
    console.log(testState);         // output: "previous state"
    setTestState("changed state");
    console.log(testState);         // output: "previous state", expected "changed state"
  }

  return (
    <div>      
      {testState}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `setTestState()` handles the changes asynchronously. That's why you have the old state in the second `console.log()` as well because that's running synchronously.

To capture state changes you can use `useEffect()` hook.

I suggest to use as the following:

```
const [testState, setTestState] = useState('previous state');

useEffect(() => {
   setGrid();
}, []);

const setGrid = () => {
   console.log('oldState', testState);

   setTestState('changed state');
};

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('newState', testState);

   // ... actions after state change
}, [testState]);
```

Suggested read: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The setTestState() is an asynchronous method. Similar to the setState() method. So your second console.log(testState) runs before the full execution of setTestState(), because of this your console.log(testState) prints the old state.

If you want to make sure that your setTestState() method is working or not you can use **useEffect()** for it which works similar to the componentDidUpdate.

```
useEffect( () => {
    console.log("updated state", testState)
}, [ 'testState' ]);
```